# SQL Server delete after first occurence

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm searching SCCM database for published applications

I get this output

```
163net_YoudaoDictionary_5.0_ZH_x32_CN_W10
```

But I want it to be

```
163net YoudaoDictionary 5.0
```

So I need method to delete everything after `_XX`  (were XX are some strings)

I used `PATINDEX('%_[A-Z]%',la.DisplayName)` to detect occurrence of _XX but how to instruct LEFT function to delete all after PATINDEX results are >1

Comment: Do you want the underscores removing as well as per your expected output?

Comment: Yes, as i wrote, output should be 163net YoudaoDictionary 5.0  (no undersore)

Comment: Wouldn't `_Yo` match `_XX` as well, or are you only looking for upper case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i found a solution:there is view in SCCM database fn_LocalizedAppProperties(1033),column title, need to join it with fn_ListLatestApplicationCIs(1033) by CI_ID

Thanks everyone for suggestions !!

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
DECLARE @DataSoruce TABLE
(
    [value] NVARCHAR(4000)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSoruce ([value])
VALUES ('163net_YoudaoDictionary_5.0_ZH_x32_CN_W10')

SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING([value], 0, PATINDEX('%[_][A-Z][A-Z]%',[value] COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2)), '_', ' ')
FROM @DataSoruce;
```

Comment: @dragan.vucanovic https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Substring()` with `Patindex()` function to find the pattern (i.e. _XX) & replace with `' '` & then further replace `'_'` with `' '`

```
DECLARE @DATA NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @DATA = '163net_YoudaoDictionary_5.0_ZH_x32_CN_W10'

SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(@DATA, SUBSTRING(@DATA, PATINDEX('%_ZH%', @DATA), LEN(@DATA)), ''), '_', ' ');
```

Result :

```
163net YoudaoDictionary 5.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
declare @str varchar(100)
set @str = '163net_YoudaoDictionary_5.0_ZH_x32_CN_W10'
select REPLACE(LEFT(@str, PATINDEX('%[_][A-Z][^a-z]%',@str COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS) - 4), '_', ' ')
```

Essentially, you need such regular expression `'%[_][A-Z][^a-z]%'` to find what you need and set collation of string searched to case-sensitive, such as `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS`.

Answer (score 1):

If your string is always the same format and length, then you can use `SUBSTRING()` and `REPLACE()` functions:

```
DECLARE @Type NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'163net_YoudaoDictionary_5.0_ZH_x32_CN_W10';

SELECT SUBSTRING(REPLACE (@Type, '_', ' '), 0, 28) AS Result;
```

Use **[REPLACE()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql)** to replace `_` with a space `' '`.

Use **[SUBSTRING()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql)** to cut needed string from your string.

If you want to use `PATINDEX()`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@Type, 0, PATINDEX('%[_][A-Z][A-Z][_]%', @Type) ), '_', ' ') AS Result;
```

Update:

You did not provide a sample data, but here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE MyData (
    STR NVARCHAR(MAX)
    );
INSERT INTO MYData VALUES
(N'163net_YoudaoDictionary_5.0_ZH_x32_CN_W10'),
(N'164net_YoudaoDictionary_4.0_HZ_x86_CN_W10_UD78_KIU7'),
(N'165net_YoudaoDictionary_4.1_ZH_x32'),
(N'166net_YoudaoDictionary_3.0_LF_x32_KO_X16'),
(N'167net_YoudaoDictionary_1.0_EX_x86_RW_B28');

SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(STR, 0, PATINDEX('%[_][A-Z][A-Z][_]%', STR) ), '_', ' ') AS Result
FROM MyData;
```

Result:

```
+-----------------------------+
|           Result            |
+-----------------------------+
| 163net YoudaoDictionary 5.0 |
| 164net YoudaoDictionary 4.0 |
| 165net YoudaoDictionary 4.1 |
| 166net YoudaoDictionary 3.0 |
| 167net YoudaoDictionary 1.0 |
+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks all, It's OK for one entry, but i have full table with application name, and can't update SCCM table     select dispplayname  from fn_ListLatestApplicationCIs(1033)

Comment: @dragan.vucanovic You can post a sample data into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Sample table:

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE (
    string nvarchar(max)
)

INSERT INTO @temp VALUES
(N'163net_YoudaoDictionary_5.0_ZH_x32_CN_W10'),
(N'157org_WhateverDictionary_7.0_smth_KJ_x64_WN_W7'),
(N''),
(NULL)
```

Script:

```
SELECT RTRIM(REPLACE(LEFT(string,PATINDEX('%[_][A-Z][A-Z][_]%',string COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2)),'_',' '))
FROM @temp
```

Output:

```
(No column name)
163net YoudaoDictionary 5.0
157org WhateverDictionary 7.0 smth

NULL
```

Explanation:

I guess you know what stands for [RTRIM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rtrim-transact-sql), [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql), [LEFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/left-transact-sql), [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql). And `COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2` binary collation means the search is a straight forward byte comparison, which is apparently quicker. More [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support) *Binary collations* part.